# Laravel: Class 'CategoryModel' not found. How to access a model inside a sub-folder?

Tags: exception, model, laravel, laravel-4, nested

My `CategoryModel` works when I place it inside `models` folder. But when I place it inside a sub-folder like `user`. It throws the above error.

The model is being called inside the controller as shown..

```
public function home() {
    // titling
    $data['title'] = "Price Soldier - Home";
    // controlling
    $data['current_category'] = "cellphones";
    $data['current_brand'] = "all";
    $data['current_sorting'] = "latest";
    $data['categories'] = CategoryModel::get_all_categories();
    $data['brands'] = BrandModel::get_all_brands_by_category("cellphones");
    $data['latests'] = ProductModel::get_products("cellphones", "all", "latest");
    $data['mvs'] = ProductModel::get_products("cellphones", "all", "most viewed");
    $data['plths'] = ProductModel::get_products("cellphones", "all", "price low to high");
    $data['phtls'] = ProductModel::get_products("cellphones", "all", "price high to high");
    // viewing
    return View::make("pages.user.home", $data);
}
```

So, In simple terms, how can I access a model inside a sub folder?

Comment: 'composer dump-autoload' was executed after moving it to models/user?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro No I didn't execute it. Elaborate plz

Comment: You need to. Just execute this command at the command line, so composer rebuild your auloading classes. Every time you use a class in PHP it must be: 1) required (you can do that in your code, but you shouldn't); or 2) autoloaded (Composer does that for you), or else it will give you this error you're looking at.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro This helped. You should send an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute on your command line:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or

```
composer dump-autoload -o
composer dumpautoload -o (dash is optional)
```

For better optimization and speed.

Every time you use a class in PHP it must be:

1) required (you can do that in your code, but you shouldn't); or

2) autoloaded (Composer does that for you).

Or else it will give you this error you're looking at.